# Is it possible to use realm with react native to build an app for windows UWP?

Tags: android, ios, windows, react-native, uwp

Is it possible to use Realm with React Native to build an app for Windows UWP?

I can get Realm to work fine on iOS and Android but not on Windows. Is it supported or not?

Comment: Another new option to consider is [ReactXP](https://microsoft.github.io/reactxp/blog/) I'm not sure if Realm will work with it though and the framework's support for UWP is in progress so some APIs may not work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. I actually just ran across this today: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/04/13/react-native-on-the-universal-windows-platform/#fc471ZrRU0ukJgHC.97

Comment: This says you can use React Native on UWP, but do you know if you can use **Realm for React Native** on UWP??

Answer (score -1):

Not yet, but there an issue, [Support for ReactNative for Windows #432](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/432), opened.

Here is [another answer for the realm-core repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42281799/7172223)