# Realm Support for UWP

Tags: database, windows, uwp, realm

I am working on a windows 10 app, and I have to store data locally, but I am new to Entity Framework, So kindly suggest me which database technique should i use for storing data locally?

Also please someone let me know if Relam supports windows 10 apps for UWP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update: Realm released UWP support.

Check the announcement here: https://news.realm.io/news/realm-mobile-database-for-universal-windows-platform/

---

*Old answer:* 
There an Issue, [realm/realm-core#2059](https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/2059), discussing this topic. So far it's not solved, it seems you're not the first one asking Realm to support UWP. Xamarin is supported, though.

**So there's no support right now for the Universal Windows Platform** on Realm. Encryption, multi-process support and ARM support seem to be the biggest issues stopping this platform to be supported.

Comment: Are you sure there is still no UWP support? They seem to have made an article about [Realm being available for Windows Desktop](https://realm.io/news/realm-microsoft-xamarin-1-0-azure-windows-desktop/)?

Comment: Okay I asked [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/509#issuecomment-280647413), console apps and WPF are supported, UWP and Windows 10 apps aren't supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [MarcelloDB](http://marcellodb.org), which is an object database built to be used / embedded in apps.

It supports UWP and Xamarin(iOs and Android), most of the code is written in a portable class library, so you can port your code across the different platforms easily as well.

It allows you to store plain C# objects (incuding child properties, lists and collections)